# Log file not updating when I run my java app as a service

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, autostart

I am not good in Ubuntu and I have the problem. I have my Java+Spring app which works perfect and it writes log file in the app directory when I run it as:

```
sudo java -jar MyApp.jar &
```

But I want to run it as a service so I searched the web and did everything [like here](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example). The app works fine, but the log file has no update any more.

Comment: My guess is that there is permission problem because of different users. Are you checked permissions on the log file? I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: @BoskoMijin But the owner of App folder is root. And when I run stop I see that my app is running under the root too.

Comment: I am not clear with all the info, but if you have different users, there can be permission problem (which I think is in this case). When you are running the application with the command shown in the question, you are forcing run as super user. When you are starting service, it can belong to other user. Can you check this?

Comment: @BoskoMijin I've just gave access to everyone for this folder, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more info on HOW you are running your program "as a service" and HOW you're creating/opening your log file in your program.
If you're creating the log file in the current working folder then probably your start script is starting your program in some other folder you're not looking for or do not have permission to write.